# document.getElementsByName does not working in Chrome and mozilla

Tags: javascript

```
cells   = document.getElementsByName('tblEst');
```

The collection returns 313 as cells.length in IE but in every other browser it is cells.length = 0
How can I access the length of this collection in chrome .I have to loop it once i get the length

```
for(i=0;i<cells.length;i++) {
    cells[i].style.display = '';
}
```

Comment: Is the code wrapped in `DOMContentLoaded`?

Comment: yes it is there in DOM . If I do view source I can see everything but since I have to hide and show them depending upon requirement. first time It works as expected but then when this function get fired I do not get the length and so it creates problem

Comment: could you create a small fiddle

Comment: bigger issue is the code doesnot shows any error in fiddle or chrome development tool. because of simple reason it only the length I am not getting rest of the code is fine.

Comment: You need to post more of your code, what you posted above will work in every major browser.